# Filter one record by one or more categories within a single column

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-filter-view

In Google Sheet, how to represent, if possible, an item that belongs to one or more categories in such a way that it is easy to filter by one or multiple categories.

Ideally in a manner where the various categories fit within 1 cell:

[image]

And not like where the categories are scatted among multiple columns:

[image]

Comment: Could you share the spreadsheet you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

possible with custom formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2, "Quad")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think combining `join()` and `filter()` will accomplish what you are looking to do.

```
=join(",",iferror(filter($B$1:$G$1,$B2:$G2="Yes"),""))
```

You will most likely need to change the ranges. $B$1:$G$1 will need to reference the header row.  $B2:$G2 is the range the looks to see if the value equals "Yes".